# Should questions about Screeps go to Arqade or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Should questions about Screeps (A game where you play by writing JavaScript code) and similar games be on Arqade or on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 28):

Questions about writing/debugging the javascript code should go on stack overflow, but questions about game functionality and strategy should fit in here on Arqade.

In fact, the [screeps official docs](https://screeps.com/docs/) direct users to post their gameplay questions here:

> If you have a question please do not hesitate asking on StackOverflow in case of coding issues and on Arqade in case of gameplay issues. Don't forget to add the tag 'screeps', we regularly monitor the questions and try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: The docs? The docs are the worst part about playing screeps...

Answer (score 5):

If you have a question about playing the game that does not inherently involve JavaScript, you should ask here. That means that if you are trying to get the game to work, or if you want help with strategy, this is a good place to ask.

If you have a question about implementing a strategy in code, or fixing your existing code, you should ask on Stack Overflow.